# Trying to add a 2 character state code to my National Parks project

Tags: javascript, jquery, api, curl

In my search, when I add states such as Michigan or Ohio it returns back National State Parks this part works fine. My problem is that when you just add the State abbreviation it doesn't work so well.

In the API documentation, I can add 'stateCode A comma delimited list of 2 character state codes.' at which I have. In turn it spits out a CURL at which I am not familiar with at all. This is the curl: curl -X GET "https://developer.nps.gov/api/v1/parks?stateCode=AK%2C%20AL%2C%20AR%2C%20AZ%2C%20CA%2C%20CO%2C%20CT%2C%20DC%2C%20DE%2C%20FL%2C%20GA%2C%20HI%2C%20IA%2C%20ID%2C%20IL%2C%20IN%2C%20KS%2C%20KY%2C%20LA%2C%20MA%2C%20MD%2C%20ME%2C%20MI%2C%20MN%2C%20MO%2C%20MS%2C%20MT%2C%20NC%2C%20ND%2C%20NE%2C%20NH%2C%20NJ%2C%20NM%2C%20NV%2C%20NY%2C%20OH%2C%20OK%2C%20OR%2C%20PA%2C%20RI%2C%20SC%2C%20SD%2C%20TN%2C%20TX%2C%20UT%2C%20VA%2C%20VT%2C%20WA%2C%20WI%2C%20WV%2C%20WY&api_key=VBJvAbqe0D9w3pyhaHcw4p4MB2dNgSgxMjvCbyEH" -H "accept: application/json"

How can I add this to my javascript to make this work when I just want to put in the 2 character state abbreviation?

```js
"use strict";

const apiKey = "VBJvAbqe0D9w3pyhaHcw4p4MB2dNgSgxMjvCbyEH";
const searchURL = "https://api.nps.gov/api/v1/parks";

function formatQueryParams(params) {
  const queryItems = Object.keys(params).map(
    key => `${encodeURIComponent(key)}=${encodeURIComponent(params[key])}`
  );
  return queryItems.join("&");
}

function displayResults(responseJson) {
  // if there are previous results, remove them
  console.log(responseJson);
  $("#results-list").empty();
  // iterate through the items array
  for (let i = 0; i < responseJson.data.length; i++) {
    // for each park object in the items
    //array, add a list item to the results
    //list with the park title, description,
    //and thumbnail
    $("#results-list").append(
      `<li><h3>${responseJson.data[i].fullName}</h3>
      <p>${responseJson.data[i].description}</p>
      <a href='${responseJson.data[i].url}'>${responseJson.data[i].url}</a>
      </li>`
    );
  }
  //display the results section
  $("#results").removeClass("hidden");
}

function getNationalParksInfo(query, maxResults = 10) {
  const params = {
    key: apiKey,
    q: query,
    limit: maxResults - 1
  };
  const queryString = formatQueryParams(params);
  const url = searchURL + "?" + queryString;

  console.log(url);

  fetch(url)
    .then(response => {
      if (response.ok) {
        return response.json();
      }
      throw new Error(response.statusText);
    })
    .then(responseJson => displayResults(responseJson))
    .catch(err => {
      $("#js-error-message").text(`Something went wrong: ${err.message}`);
    });
}

function watchForm() {
  $("form").submit(event => {
    event.preventDefault();
    const searchTerm = $("#js-search-term").val();
    const maxResults = $("#js-max-results").val();
    getNationalParksInfo(searchTerm, maxResults);
  });
}

$(watchForm);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <title>National Parks by Location</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script
      src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"
      integrity="sha256-2Kok7MbOyxpgUVvAk/HJ2jigOSYS2auK4Pfzbm7uH60="
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <h1>Your National Parks</h1>

      <form id="js-form">
        <label for="search-term">Search term</label>
        <input type="text" name="search-term" id="js-search-term" required />

        <label for="max-results">Maximum results to return</label>
        <input
          type="number"
          name="max-results"
          id="js-max-results"
          value="10"
        />

        <input type="submit" value="Go!" />
      </form>

      <p id="js-error-message" class="error-message"></p>
      <section id="results" class="hidden">
        <h2>Search results</h2>
        <ul id="results-list"></ul>
      </section>
    </div>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

The desired outcome is for me to either type the full state name of the state abbreviation and I get the same search results.

Comment: If I query ```https://developer.nps.gov/api/v1/parks?stateCode=AK&api_key=VBJvAbqe0D9w3pyhaHcw4p4MB2dNgSgxMjvCbyEH``` I get a json returned with the appropriate data. Are you sure your query is being built correctly?

Comment: When inserting the full state names it works fine. Maybe I am looking at this the wrong way?

Comment: so where you ```console.log(url)``` a search with ```js-search-term``` = 'AK' the string logged is the same as the one I used?

Comment: I think I have figured it out, in the https://www.nps.gov/subjects/developer/api-documentation.htm#/parks/getPark within Parks related data it says I have to use stateCode(A comma delimited list of 2 character state codes.) So know I am trying to figure out how to add stateCode in the object of const params = {
    key: apiKey,
    q: query,    
    limit: maxResults - 1
  };